# Eastern Orthodoxy - When a liturgical hymn to a Saint is composed (such as a Troparion), how is the mode/tone for the hymn chosen?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, hymns, music

Canons, troparia, kontakia, aposticha, stichera, etc. all have a tone/mode associated with them.  How does the author of the hymn choose which mode/tone to use?  Is it the same for all, or is it a little different for each type of hymn?

(I'm referring here specifically to hymns written to commemorate Saints.  Hymns composed for the Octoechos or for Pascha I already somewhat understand why they are written for a particular tone/mode).